# Extract String arrays from List

Tags: java, casting

Developing a Java Android App but this is a straight up Java question i think.

I have  List declared as follows;

```
List list= new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

I want to extract each String [] in a loop;

```
for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   //get each String[]
   String[] teamDetails = (String[])list.get(i);
}
```

This errors, I am guessing it just doesn't like me casting the String[] like this.

Can anyone suggest a way to extract the String[] from my List?

Comment: my bad i changed code last sec for clarity, my effort failed :) editing now

Comment: What is the error? This should work (I'm guessing you missed `()` in the `size` call).

Comment: your declaration should be  `List<String[]> list= new ArrayList<>();`.  This way you wouldn't need the cast

Comment: Don't use rawtypes. Ever. If you don't know what a rawtype is, this read about Java generics before "dev'ing" any apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `List<String[]>` and you can use the more up-to-date looping construct:

```
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    //I want to extract each String[] in a loop;
    for ( String[] teamDetails : list) {

    }

    // To extract a specific one.
    String[] third = list.get(2);
```

Comment: this is a go-er, now a confession. The loop is artificially put there for the purpose of the question. How would i reach into each String[] in list if just given a integer of the appropriate array?

Comment: @Fearghal exactly as you think: `final String[] array = list.get(i)`.

Comment: @Fearghal - In the same way you already do - `list.get(index)` - just make sure you declare as `List<String[]>`.

Comment: I got an error. maybe i have made a mistake in something above. java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Comment: @Fearghal - Added a further example for how to get a specific one.

Comment: See my updated question and prev reply to you - this causes an error

Comment: @Fearghal - Check what line the error is on - it won't be on the assignment as that is correct.

Comment: unfortunately its at the line String[] teamDetails = list.get(i);

Comment: @Fearghal - That seems unlikely. My code compiles fine.

Comment: Im not 100% but you are right, i dont think its your solution. Il mark it as answer. Thx a mill for your help, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the list this way

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    //get each String[]
    String[] teamDetails = list.get(i);
}
```

Moreover the call of your size function was wrong you need to add the brackets

Comment: You don't need to cast.

Comment: the cast is not necessary, the declaration will solve Fearghal's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*ArrayList to Array Conversion */
            String array[] = new String[arrlist.size()];              
            for(int j =0;j<arrlist.size();j++){
              array[j] = arrlist.get(j);
            }

//OR
/*ArrayList to Array Conversion */
        String frnames[]=friendsnames.toArray(new String[friendsnames.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In for loop change `list.size` to `list.size()`

And it works fine Check this https://ideone.com/jyVd0x

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change declaration from 
`List list= new ArrayList<String[]>();` to 
`List<String[]> list = new ArrayList();`

After that you can do something like

```
String[] temp =  new String[list.size];

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)`
{
temp[i] = list.get(i);
}
```